# How to make an offline AngularJS/Cordova app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, cordova, offline

I have a AngularJS app (embedded in a Cordova app).
To get and set data, it uses a REST API (that runs on a Django backend server).

I need that the app keeps working for several features even if the network is down.
For example, I'm expecting this kind of behaviour:

**Online Mode**

- A client does something in the app
- a POST request (to create data) is sent to the API
- The client gets a "Thank you for doing xxx"

**Fallback offline mode**

- A client buys something on the app
- The client gets a "xxx can't be done right now, but it will be done as soon as possible"
- Nothing can be sent to the server since we're offline. So how to do? Is there a way to put the API requests in a queue that will be executed when we're back to online mode?

How would you technically design this? It seems there is lots of differents technologies for offline mode, and it's a little bit confusing to me. Any guidance would be welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't say "thank you for buying" **before** the request has returned successfully, even when online! You should wait until you know the purchase is complete.

Comment: Ok it was a bad example, but sometimes I realy don't need to wait for a server response before sending data.

Comment: @DavidW. really? Could you please share one of those situations?

Comment: That won't help me guys :( I edited the question sothat we can focus on the real question which is "how to queue calls to the server"

Comment: You can't reliably say "it will be done as soon as possible," unless the request is sent and is waiting in a queue *on the server*. I would just try the request, and if there's any error, tell the user, "The request can't be completed at this time, because (reasons). Please try again later."

Comment: You can't know that your app will continue to run in the background on the user's device to try to complete the request.

Comment: I agree, but in my case it's absolutely not a problem.

Comment: Hey @DavidW, I noticed you didn't choose an accepted answer on this one

Answer (score 1):

I would like to use such app, that would make me feel stupid. But there is

You can check network status with this plugin.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/doc/index.md

Each request will need a switch between sending HTTP POST and saving POST data to local storage.

Then you would just create callbacks for following events:

```
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
function onOffline() {
    // Turn on saving to local storage
}

document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
function onOnline() {
    // Read local storage, send all requests
}
```

Comment: Thanks it seems to be a good way to do it too (similar to the lukevp one, but without requesting the server if you're offline).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the pressure in the comments are not to do this.  We have this functionality in an app we are developing.

Basically we package up the iOS app as a Cordova wrapped web container and also run a local proxy server as part of the app.  It passes all data through it to the web service.  If the requests fail, it returns an identifier to the app so you can determine that the connection to the server is down, and the app then  saves the requests to localStorage.  That way the UI can adapt to being in "offline mode."  you can later push data from the app through the proxy once the connection to the server is restored.  The app connects directly to the proxy rather than to a webservice.

As far as I'm aware, there's not an easy library to solve this situation though, and you have to be aware of how the requests will affect the online application (can things go out of sync in your system, if the user runs requests that are cached until later?)

It is definitely something that can be done, though.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the way I should do it :)